# Set custom production firing time in ACT-R

Tags: lisp

When defining a model in ACT-R, I would like to set for each of my productions, a different firing time.

How could I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not too many ACT-R modelers here, huh?

First off, keep a copy of the [ACT-R reference manual](http://act-r.psy.cmu.edu/actr6/reference-manual.pdf) handy. This a great resource that answers 90% of the questions you will have.

You can set a production's action time using `(spp <production-name> :at <time>)` or you can set the default action time using `(sgp :dat <time>)`.  Times are in seconds, so the default is .05.

That being said, you should modify these parameters **very** rarely, if at all.  The whole point of production firing time is that it's supposed to represent a psychological constant.  If you're tinkering with this, your model may fit the data but is less likely to be psychologically plausible.  And if you don't care about psychological plausibility, then you shouldn't be using ACT-R! But there's an exception to every rule, so proceed with caution.

Comment: What if I want to model different human mind conditions? A person with dementia doesn't have the same reaction time as a person suffering from alzheimer, etc. I would like to set some parameters, according to the concrete person's profile. Is that possible?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure, but you've got the right idea.  As you might be aware, age related differences are often modeled by changing :dat. I think if you pick and choose which productions to change using :at, some people may complain about overfitting your parameters, but I certainly understand your concern-- not all dementia patients are alike.  If you're able to validate your model with a novel data set, I think you can avoid some of that criticism.  My naive intuition is that dementia can be modeled using noisy activation and utility values-- which can cause slower memory retrievals, etc.

Comment: But I'm sure you know the domain better than myself, so it's just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

While this is a bit old, this question still comes up fairly high on Google when searching for ACT-R production firing times, so I feel it is acceptable to post a response.

As a published ACT-R modeler with 4 years under my belt, I would like to echo Jeff's statements. You very, very rarely modify most ACT-R parameters for the exact reason Jeff stated. All aspects of ACT-R and the amount of time certain modules take to fire are empirically backed by many studies. If you start changing these, then your model, like Jeff said, is completely implausible. While some modelers do change these values, they have empirical data to back up their reasons for changing any parameters.